# ASP.NET data protection - how to properly implement ILookupProtectorKeyRing using Azure key vault

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-keyvault, data-protection

I'm wondering how I should go about implementing the ILookupProtectorKeyRing, my implementation currently uses an IKeyManager from Azure Key Vault to load all key versions and return those keys as a list (implementation below)

```
public class ApplicationLookupProtectorKeyRing : ILookupProtectorKeyRing
{
    public IDictionary<string, IKey> Keys { get; set; }

    private readonly IKeyManager _keyManager;
    private readonly object _keyDictionaryLock;

    public ApplicationLookupProtectorKeyRing(IKeyManager keyManager)
    {
        Keys = new Dictionary<string, IKey>();
        _keyManager = keyManager;
        _keyDictionaryLock = new object();
    }

    public string this[string keyId]
    {
        get
        {
            ReloadKeys();
            lock (_keyDictionaryLock)
            {
                return Keys[keyId].KeyId.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    public string CurrentKeyId
    {
        get
        {
            ReloadKeys();
            lock (_keyDictionaryLock)
            {
                return GetAllKeyIds()
                    .Where(w => Keys[w].ActivationDate <= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
                    .OrderByDescending(o => Keys[o].ActivationDate)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetAllKeyIds()
    {
        ReloadKeys();
        lock (_keyDictionaryLock)
        {
            return Keys.Keys;
        }
    }

    private void ReloadKeys()
    {
        lock (_keyDictionaryLock)
        {
            if (!_keyManager.GetCacheExpirationToken().IsCancellationRequested && Keys.Count != 0) { return; }

            var keys = _keyManager.GetAllKeys()
                .Where(w => !w.IsRevoked)
                .ToList();

            if (!keys.Any())
            {
                keys.Add(_keyManager.CreateNewKey(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7)));
            }

            Keys.Clear();
            keys.ForEach(key => Keys.Add(key.KeyId.ToString(), key));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the ILookupProtector requires a symmetric key for the AES encryption, these KeyIds are just plain guids and thus cannot be used as the keys, I can just generate a new key using AES and use that but how would I go about persisting that key and/or is there a better way of doing this in the first place?

Comment: I did blog about the Data Protection API and Azure Key Vault here https://www.edument.se/en/blog/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault  perhaps it can give you some hints.

Comment: @ToreNestenius Thanks for the blogpost although not quite what I was looking for, the implementation with the ILookupProtector/ILookupProtectorKeyRing are used in combination with personal data protection, protecting fields like an e-mail address etc, not the tokens.

Comment: Aha, anyway, worth a try :-)